# Writing a firefox extension versus writing a firefox service - what's the difference?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am learning to write a firefox extension and noticed that there's a different category of extensions known as "services".

What allows an `extensions` add-on to be classified as a `services` add-on?

Does a `services` add-on mean that the add-on uses Mozilla's Social API?

Extensions:-

[image]

Services:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Services" are add-ons implementing the [Social API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Social_API)

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation from mozilla stating that this is so.

Comment: @CalvinCheng install a Social Provider and it will appear as a service.